# PGM and WebGL General Information

Tags: canvas, webgl

I really could use some help here. I've read up and many of the sites I've checked all say the same thing -- that WebGL uses canvas.

However, my qustion is -- even OpenGL uses the canvas element. What makes WebGL any different?

Also, if a PGM uses canvas, is it by default a WebGL?

I'm sorry if this seems like a dumb question. :)

Comment: I don't think I understand this question. PGM is a file format and WebGL is an API. You can't really compare and contrast the two.

Answer (score 1):

A canvas is just something in the DOM that JS can draw on using a context.  You can use a 2D context, which is what HTML5 introduced, or you can use the WebGL context.  It is with the context that you draw things with onto the canvas.

The browser has to have support for the context type when calling canvas.getContext in order for it to work.  See the [MDC guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebGL/Getting_started_with_WebGL) for a bit more info.